# Chrome Extension XMLHttpRequest returning 0 using HTTPS and non-conventional port

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I'm using this function to send a `XHR` request to a server which uses `HTTPS` and a non-conventional port: `https://www.example.com:10000/request.php`

```
function AJAXInteraction(url, callback, str) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", url, true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
       var resp = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
       approveResponse (resp);
    }
  }
  xhr.send(str);
}
```

In my `manifest` I've set the permissions to `"*://*/*"`

```
{
  "name": "Test Extension",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "version": "2.0",
  "description": "Extension Admin Util.",
  "devtools_page": "background.html",
  "content_scripts": [
    { "matches": ["http://*/*"], "js": ["content_script.js"] }
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "*://*/*",
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

The `XHR` is returning `0` and using Developer Tools the Network tab shows it was `cancelled`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Pssst. Your question is missing a question. Also, can you test that in a Dev/Canary version of Chrome to make sure it's not a bug-that-was-fixed-already?

Comment: What kind of certificate does the server use? Does your browser trust it?

Comment: It's self-signed but the browser trust it (the `https` sign is green)

Comment: How are you calling the AJAXInteraction function?

Comment: @javsmo -> `var ajax = new AJAXInteraction(url, approveResponse, querystr); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that the non-conventional port is the problem.

It usually happens to me when I'm making the request on a link or button event and I don't remove the default action of the event and the page changes and cancel the AJAX request.

If this is your problem, use `event.preventDefault();` on your click event as shown below.

```
$('a.action-foo').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    //Make your AJAX request
});
```